# Choosing between extended classes inside constructor

Tags: java, processing, abstract

I am writing a java (processing) library for unexperienced students, and am looking for the best architecture for implementing it.
Initialization of an object should be as close as possible to this:

```
myObject = new General("type1");
```

Such that myObject will become an instance of `Type1` which extends `General`:

```
class General {
  public General() {}
}

class Type1 extends General {
  public Type1() {}
}

class Type2 extends General {
  public Type1() {}
}
```

As far as I know, this isn't possible (choosing between extended classes during initialization), but I'm looking for the closest solution possible.
So far, my best solution is to make a static initializer inside `General`:

```
class General {
  ...
  static General init (String type) {
    General temp;
    if (type.equals("type1") {
      temp = new Type1();
    }
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

and the initialization is:

```
General myObject;
myObject = General.init("type1");
```

This is far from ideal...

thanks.

Comment: Why not use `new Type1()` directly?

Comment: You probably already know this, but your static initializer is known as the [Static Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info) pattern.

Comment: @RotoRa - The answer is pretty complicated and specific for this case. I have a lot of extended classes, of which the users don't need to know. They get a hardware device with it's name written on it, but the use of the library should keep as general as possible.

Comment: @jaco0646 - Yes. I'm looking for a solution "without a factory"...

Comment: You can't choose between subclasses inside the main class constructor. This isn't how Java works. A factory would be the easiest thing for the users to see.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will quite difficult to give a better suggestion, if you can' t give more details. My next questions would have been: What is the difference between `Type1` and `Type2`? Why do they extend from `General`? Why are you using inherance in the first place? (NB "a lot of extended classes" looks like a red flag to me) Where do the strings `"type1"`/`"type2"` come from? Do they need to be strings? Basically you may have a XY problem and you may need to reconsider your original approach.

Comment: Good questions, so I'll try to answer:
The goal is for the users to have the ability to create an object of a specific class to represent a hardware device from a given ecosystem. Each device has a name, so it seems to me that using the device name as string "classifier" is logical.
This can be implemented without any inheritance, but using a single class for the users to use can make it very simple to use (for example, after setting the device type, the student can add a command like ```myObject.help()``` and get specific instructions printed to the console.

Answer (score 2):

you can make a factory class that manages initialization.
instead of doing it inside the parent.

```
    // Empty vocabulary of actual object
public interface IPerson
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Villager : IPerson
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Village Person";
    }
}

public class CityPerson : IPerson
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "City Person";
    }
}

public enum PersonType
{
    Rural,
    Urban
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of Factory - Used to create objects.
/// </summary>
public class Factory
{
    public IPerson GetPerson(PersonType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case PersonType.Rural:
                return new Villager();
            case PersonType.Urban:
                return new CityPerson();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just expain my down vote: While this is a correct implentation of a factory pattern, the question OP is asking is: What is the best architecture? And I don't believe a factory would be the correct approach.

Comment: @RoToRa Then what **do** you believe to be the best architecture?

Comment: FYI, this example is what Head First Design Patterns calls a "Simple Factory" not to be confused with the GoF patterns.

Comment: This is a better solution than using the static initializer, but for the user of the library it looks the same. Can there be anything which can be initialized inside the constructor? Or in some other elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

The *State* design pattern can be a solution here. Rather than the constructor argument changing the type of the object (which isn't possible) it can set a field of the object, to make it behave as if its type is different.

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

public class Main {
    private interface MyInterface {
        String foo();
        int bar();
    }

    private static class Type1 implements MyInterface {
        @Override public String foo() { return "lorem ipsum "; }
        @Override public int bar() { return 6; }
    }

    private static class Type2 implements MyInterface {
        @Override public String foo() { return "dolor sit amet"; }
        @Override public int bar() { return 7; }
    }

    public static class General {
        private final MyInterface type;

        public General(String type) {
            try {
                this.type = (MyInterface) Class
                        .forName("stackoverflow.questions.Main$" + type)
                        .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type: " + type);
            }
        }

        public String method1() { return type.foo(); }
        public int method2() { return type.bar(); }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        General one = new General("Type1");
        General two = new General("Type2");
        System.out.println(one.method1() + two.method1());
        System.out.println(one.method2() * two.method2());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks almost perfect for my use, besides the fact that it missuses the idea of the **state** design pattern, as the state is only set at the initialization of the object. I really believe in choosing whatever works but I wonder if there is any solution that can be really considered as "good coding" for this problem.

Comment: The GoF occasionally use the word _degenerate_ to describe simplified forms of their patterns. For example, "_A decorator can be viewed as a degenerate composite with only one component_," or "_You can think of a class in [some] languages as a degenerate factory that creates only one kind of product._" I think they might consider this a degenerate state with no outgoing transitions. It is simplified, but no less valid.